# Stumped with WorksheetFunction.Match() in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This is some VBA code I've written for Excel. I'm trying to match entries in Sheet1 with those in Sheet2. The structure of both sheets is as follows:

```
DATE | ID |
----- ----
Date1 ID1
Date2 ID2...
```

In my code, I loop through the rows of the first sheet, and set the values from each particular row as part of my `MATCH()` query, in hopes of finding these same values in the second sheet. When I do, I want `MATCH()` to return the row index it finds these values in, so I can use that same row to input further information from the first sheet. This query uses multiple criteria, as indicated by both the `value` and `searchRange` variables (I'm trying to use the multiple criteria via concatenation method, as seen in [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/59482) article).

The problem is, I consistently get a WorksheetFunction.Match could not be used error. When I used one single criteria (the ID), the function worked. When I tried to use multiple ones, it failed, even though I followed the instructions seen in the previously linked article. Any suggestions or ideas to fix this would be appreciated.

```
Sub runComparison(Sheet1 As String, Sheet2 As String)

    Dim rowCount As Variant, columnCount As Variant, information As Variant
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim value As String, searchRange As String

    Sheets(Sheet2).Select

    'Array of the number of rows in both sheets
    rowCount = Array(Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row, Sheets(Sheet2).Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row)

    'Array of the number of columns in both sheets
    columnCount = Array(Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column, Sheets(Sheet2).Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column)

    'The range in which we will look for the date and the ID 
    searchRange = CStr(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(rowCount(1), 1)).Address & "&" & Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(rowCount(1), 2)).Address)

    counter = 2
    Do Until counter = rowCount(0)

        'Sets the search term equal to the current cell in Sheet1
        value = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(counter, 1) & "&" & Sheets(Sheet2).Cells(counter, 2)

        ' Attempts to set the cell in the 8th column in the same row in which the search term is found equal to a certain value from the search term's row
        Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(value, searchRange, 0), 8) = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(counter, columnCount(0)).value

        counter = counter + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Edit: Here's some sample input

```
value = '7/14/2014&ESTUOUW1046465464'
searchRange = '$A2:$A298&$B2:B298'
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Thanks for clarifying in comments. I removed my original answer as it pertains only to the regular "Match" function, and I see the reference/example and understand what you're trying to do now which involves an array formula.

Let's try this using `Application.Evaluate` which will avoid the need to put this formula in a cell. Using the example data from MS, I did this which seems to work:

```
Sub test()

Dim value As String
Dim srcRange As String

value = "D2&E2"
srchRange = "$A$2:$A$5&$B$2:$B$5"

Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=MATCH(" & value & "," & srchRange & ",0)")


End Sub
```

Applying that in your code, I think would be like below. YOu will still want to `Dim matchVal as Variant` to hold the result of the formula evaluation, I think.  Then do this:

```
Do Until counter = rowCount(0)

    'Sets the search term equal to the current cell in Sheet1
    value = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(counter, 1) & "&" & Sheets(Sheet2).Cells(counter, 2)

    '## Assign the result of the  Match function to a variable
    matchVal = Application.Evaluate("=MATCH(" & value & "," & searchRange & ",0)")

    '## Check for errors, and handle as needed:
    If IsError(matchVal) Then
        'modify as needed, this highlight the cell with the non-matched value
        ' you might omit this line and simply ignore it, or you could
        ' display a MsgBox prompt, etc.
        Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(counter, columnCount(0)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Else:
        Cells(matchVal, 8) = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(counter, columnCount(0)).value
    End If

    counter = counter + 1

Loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, but the range isn't from A2:B298 - it's two ranges put together with the & sign, each range being an entire column. I do that because I'm working with multiple criteria, just like it's illustrated in the article I linked above. I'm just trying to replicate that same behavior - here's the link to what I'm talking about: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/59482

Comment: Well that article pertains to functions *on the worksheet* and also specifically notes that you must enter this function as an *array function*.  Right now, you're doing neither!  Let me see if I can make that work in the VBA :)

Comment: That formula also uses the `Index` function as part of the array formula, which you're also not doing. I don't think that part is needed... will update shortly.

Comment: @user2254 have you had a chance to try out the new/revised answer? Let me know if it works, and if so, do consider "Accepting" the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I went as far as copying and pasting your implementation, with no luck.